# Will this react code break the framework?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

this is my react hooks code:

```
function Child({lookup}){
    var [count,set_count]=React.useState(0)
    function diff(){
        set_count(count+1)
    }
    lookup.diff=diff
    return <div>{count}</div>
}

function Parent(){
    var [lookup,set_lookup]=React.useState({})
    return <div>
        <Child {...{lookup}}/>
        <button onClick={_=>lookup.diff(1)}>up</button>
    </div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />,document.querySelector('#root') );
```

This code demos a simple way to call a child component inner method from a parent component. it works as planned but uses coding tricks that I didn't see anywhere else. I am pretty much sure it is not idiomatic.

my question is: based on how react hooks works, will it potentially crash in some unexpected ways?

Comment: It'll work, but it's extremely weird. I'd use a better method. Do you want suggestions on other ways?

Comment: it is absolutely weird, yes. but is is short and it works in my test program. are there in standardized  ways to do it in react hooks?  I am aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent , but their solutions are overly verbose to my taste

Comment: I don't suspect it will crash, but goes completely against what/how React was designed to work and reason about, i.e. data flows in ***one*** direction, parent to child, in the form of props. In such a simple example it seems to me you should [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the parent, or follow the suggestions in the accepted answer in the SO post you linked to pass a ref from parent to child.

Comment: Its absolutely an anti-pattern because [Props Are Read Only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only), lifting state up, using ref are the common patterns to situations like this. Although they "verbose" to your taste they still the recommended solutions.